# Cannot connect to any Wifi network in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, network-manager, internet

I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 from 19.10 and my wifi adapter is not connecting to any Wifi network. It scans all available networks but is unable to connect to any network.I tried all possible solutions found in the internet but no use. Please help!

Following are the details of my wireless card:DMI

```
 *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 15
       serial: 04:d4:c4:e2:da:b4
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
       resources: irq:49 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7804000-f7804fff memory:f7800000-f7803fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: wlp4s0
       version: 00
       serial: 80:91:33:c9:2b:d5
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw_8822ce driverversion=5.4.0-29-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:62 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f7600000-f760ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@1:3
       logical name: enxfcde56ff0106
       serial: fc:de:56:ff:01:06
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.1.101 link=yes multicast=yes
```

[wireless-info](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/SFjbcR6Z24/)

Comment: You were not supposed to post the contents of `wireless-info` script. You should run the cript and post the results.

Comment: @Pilot6 rtl8821ce is not the same as his rtw_8822ce device. Abinav already has the correct driver installed.

Comment: The device is the same. Probably the in-tree driver is bad. @chili555

Comment: Please post the result of running the wireless info script, not the script itself, so that we may help you. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.